# connect four set token to the right column - C

Tags: c, multidimensional-array

I need to program a connect four game.
I already have the "layout" from the gameboard and the printf.
Now i want to set the X and O to the field (column) which the player inputs.
Do you have any ideas how I could do this?
It should not be like a hundred if's and I thought about a switch case or with a struct but I really don't come arround with structs.

Comment: SO isn't a coding for hire service. You are advised to give it a try yourself and come back with specific questions as you run into places you need help.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily handle the whole layout printing with some loops, if you already have the game table in a multidimensional-array. Here is a quick demo I wrote how you could handle the logic:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define ROWS (6)
#define COLUMNS (7)

#define PLAYER_1 ('X')
#define PLAYER_2 ('O')
#define EMPTY ('#')

int main() {
    // we have 6 rows, 7 colums each
    char board[ROWS][COLUMNS];
    for(int y = 0; y < ROWS; y++) {
        for(int x = 0; x < COLUMNS; x++) {
            board[y][x] = EMPTY;
        }
    }

    // we receive some input from player 1
    // NOTE: starting at 0 nad origin of table is top left corner
    int row = 4, column = 2;

    // we change the state of the field if not already set
    if(board[row][column] != EMPTY) {
        printf("field already occupied\n");
        return 1;
    }
    // set directly to player 1 status
    board[row][column] = PLAYER_1;

    // print table
    for(int y = 0; y < ROWS; y++) {
        for(int x = 0; x < COLUMNS; x++) {
            int value = board[y][x];
            printf("%c ", value);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: hey, thank u very much. But this doesn't go along with the code i already have